# When i go from one activity to another, for some seconds I see white screen in android app

Tags: android, json, android-activity

I have made an app in which a lot of data is coming through JSON parsing which I am using in my app.

**Now, the issue is:** when i go from one activity to another, it shows blank(or white) screen for some seconds , then my activity becomes visible. Why is this blank screen showing?

Please resolve this issue....Thanks in advance

Comment: while u r going from activity to another, r u fetching data in second activty(destination activity) ?

Comment: use asynctask for this. fetch data in  doInBackground() method http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9671546/asynctask-android-example

Comment: If you're fetching lots of data in an onCreate method of an activity that could lead to blank screens. Make sure you fetch everything in a thread and show a loading dialog to show the progress.

Comment: Yes, on the basis of selection of some fields in First activity...I am doing JSON parsing and showing that result on other activity.

Comment: do fetching data on second activity.

Comment: Every cpu-intensive operation should be done on a worker thread and not in the ui main thread, which is where your activities live. You're experiencing a delay in the activity creation since in one of its callbacks methods you're doing too much work. A simple way to fix this is to use AsyncTask.

Answer (score 0):

Set android:windowDisablePreview to true in your theme